# Laravel passport not loading keys from .env file

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have copied and add private_key and public_key in .env file for passport.
But it says `local.ERROR: LogicException: Key path "file:///application/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable in /application/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:53` while generating token.

I want to load the keys from .env file.

Comment: Can you post the .env key values for private_key and public_key?

Comment: #PASSPORT KEYS
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAqbTvkqJ+BlaGRLJeuxttCtIIloJSTC28B-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIIEAAQ==-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
@VaibhavrajRoham my .env file has private_key and public_key like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the keys are written in one line without new lines except the begin and end phrase:

```
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<your private key in one line here>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<your public key in one line here>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

Otherwise the key is not validated and passport is interpreting the string as a file path.